# insert time expiration DATE format masking (MM/YYYY)

Tags: javascript, jquery

// Credit card expiration DATE format (MM/YYYY) FOR input time please help me.

Thanks in advance .

```
<div class="pay-detail">
        <label>Exp. Date</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control expdate" placeholder="10/2019" name="expdate" maxlength="7" value="" id="expdate">
    </div>

$("body").on("keyup", "#expdate", function (event) {
        var foo = $(this).val().split("/").join(""); // remove hyphens
        if (foo.length > 0) {
            foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,2}', 'g')).join("/");
        }
        $(this).val(foo);
    });
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? You should explain your question more carefully. Is it that you want to insert that data into a database? Or limit it in the inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope all you need is here as per i answered your last question.

```css
.expiration {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
.expiration input {
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 0; /* remove if you want input highlight */
}
```

```html
<span class="expiration">
    <input type="text" name="month" placeholder="MM" maxlength="2" size="2" required="true" />
    <span>/</span>
    <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="YY" maxlength="2" size="2" required="true" />
</span>
```